# How to concatenate dataframes considering column orders

Tags: python, pandas

I want to combine two dataframes:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','a',],'B':['b','b']})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'B':['b','b'],'A':['a','a']})
pd.concat([df1,df2],ignore_index=True)
```

result:

[image]

But I want the output to be like this (I want the same code as SQL's union/union all):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `numpy` to stack the two dataframes and then use `pd.DataFrame` constructor:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([df1.values,df2.values]), columns = df1.columns)
```

Output:

```
   A  B
0  a  b
1  a  b
2  b  a
3  b  a
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposition to do an *[SQL UNION ALL](https://sql.sh/cours/union/union-all)* with pandas by using [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) :

```
list_dfs = [df1, df2]

out = (
        pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(sub_df.to_numpy()) for sub_df in list_dfs], 
                  ignore_index=True)
            .set_axis(df1.columns, axis=1)
      )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)

   A  B
0  a  b
1  a  b
2  b  a
3  b  a
```